# Problem connect to FTP other server whit hostname

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp, codeigniter-3

I using codeigniter 3.1.13 , php 5.6 and i using FTP to connect to another server, which unfortunately gives the following error:

```
Unable to connect to your FTP server using the supplied hostname.
```

Ftp:

```
$config['hostname'] = 'xxxxx.xxxxxx.net'; 
$config['username'] = 'xxxxxx';
$config['password'] = 'xxxxxx';
$config['debug']    = TRUE;
$config['port']     = 21;
$config['passive']  = TRUE;
```

This is if I connect to FTP with the same information by filezilla

Library ftp: https://pastecode.io/s/uxziv8aw

What do i do?

Comment: _"I using [...] php 5.6"_ - that on its own is a huge red flag already.

Comment: @CBroe what's the solution?

Comment: 5.6 has not received any updates for years, even some of the 7.x versions are End-of-Life already. https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php This is not necessarily related to your current problem, but you should not be writing any new code for 5.6 in the year 2022 any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can connect to the server but are not able to transfer the file (as you mentioned in one of your comments), there might be 2 problems:

1. Firewall
2. Missing permission on the FTP server to write upload file.

Please be sure that your Firewall (if you have any one) does not block outgoing FTP connections and the directory on the FTP server has the needed permissions to write files into it.